# How to avoid using the is operator in c# when my method returns a base type?

Tags: c#, oop

I have an abstract base class `P`. I have two classes that inherit `P` called `I` and `O`.

I have a `Get()` method in my repository that returns `P`. This method always returns an instance of either `I` or `O` depending on a value.

```
public P Get(string pci)
{
     var a = GetAByPCI(string pci);

     if(a == 1)
         return new I();
     else if(a == 2)
         return new O();
     else
         // throw exception here.
}
```

When I call this method from another location I need to check and cast the type.

```
P p = PRepository.Get("200");

if(p is I)
    I i = (I)p;
```

I'd like to avoid having to check and downcast every time `p` above is used. I feel as though I'm doing some fundamentally wrong here, but am not certain.

**Update:** 
The derived types `I` & `O` have additional properties that need to be used but only pertain to that specific type. `P` has many abstract properties that are implemented in inheriting types. Downcasting is the only way I can get to the concrete types as needed?

Maybe the logic is entirely wrong.

Comment: Add enough methods to the base class for you to not need to interact with the derived classes.

Comment: Why do you want to have direct access to the subtypes? You shouldn't need that.

Comment: Why do you need to cast to the base types? What do they have that you don't have in the child types? In that case, is it common, and if so, why is it not in the parent type?

Comment: Can you post an example of an actual usage - i.e. what do you do with your I-s and O-s after you cast them?

Comment: Looks like strategy pattern could do the thing

Comment: If you are going to cast an object following an `is` check, you should be using the `as` operator instead and checking for `null`.  In doing this, in a nutshell, you are casting the object twice.  Use this instead:  `I i = p as I;  if(i != null) { /* use i */ }`

Comment: @Joanna Turban +1 Good comment/question. That is the Point. Sometimes you need to know the concrete type because you are doing something related to somewhat specific. Anything else is only theory in OOP and has nothing to do with the real world implementations you might see/find/need.

Comment: @JoannaTurban `I` and `O` contain many similar properties which are implemented in `P`. However there are times when I need the concrete type `I` and `O` because they have specific properties that are not common to each other. The only way I could get to concrete type is downcast but I feel as though I'm doing some fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @ChaceFields I gave you a solution within one of my two answers. If you need the concrete type you have to do a cast/unboxing but I would put this into a separate strategy (this way you get a loose coupling instead of strong bounds).

Comment: ... by the way: It seems the PRepository is a static class. Be careful with using the Repository as static implementations... they have funny sideeffects, e.g. if you need two repositories for different types of objects and want to share the same implementation.

Comment: If you don't put the properties in the base class/interface it is not possible to access them without cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of having a base class is to avoid having to deal with the subclass itself. Just add an abstract method to the base class and have it implemented in the sub-classes. This way, the calling code will simply call the method without having to do any casts. This is basic polymorphism.

Comment: ... but this solution is only possible if you can change the base class (this is not always the case, e.g. for 3rd party libraries)

Answer (score 1):

What is your intention? It seems you are not making proper use of inheritance.
If you return a P object from your methods, you either need to downcast or return the derived types.

Comment: Clarifying questions should be posted as comments (which you can make when you have 50 reputation) and shouldn't be posted as answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to be suspect of down casting.

I would look at the [template method design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx).  If you have a base class it should be used to hide the details of the subclass.

So maybe you have a method in your base class called Execute().  Inside the base class the execute method calls some protected methods, lets say Method1(), and Method2().  Method 1 would contain the shared code, method two would be abstract and the child classes would have to execute it.  Then when you get your instance back you just call Execute.  The proper Method2() will run without you having to cast downward.

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //Here's a bunch of stuff I have to do everytime
        DoSomethingTypeSpecific();
        //I could do more stuff if I needed to
    }

    protected abstract void DoSomethingTypeSpecific();
}

class MyBaseClassOne : MyBaseClass
{
    protected override void DoSomethingTypeSpecific()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(1);
    }
}

class MyBaseClassTwo : MyBaseClass
{
    protected override void DoSomethingTypeSpecific()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires to provide the processing code to be within the DoSomethingTypeSpecific... what if you can't change the class (3rd party lib) or the processing requires to invoke something the DoSomethingTypeSpecific shouldn't know?. Anyway, this might be a possible solution to solve the problem mentioned above. +1

Comment: Some guy did a downvote for your solution without comment... why the downvote? the provided solution seems to fit some scenarios. (and @Kassem got +1 for the same Intention without providing a sample)

Comment: He mentioned within an update that he wants to access properties on his POCO classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would also think about using the [Decorator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) and [composition instead of using inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Nevertheless you still need a cast if you want to access the properties that are not part of the base class.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to eleminate the cast without putting the properties into the base class but you can use the [strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx) to decouple the object creation (see [my question and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819747/how-to-decouple-mode-switching-and-commands) for an example how to do this). **The example shows how to decouple the switch-case** but you can do the same thing with the strategy pattern for analysing the result of the context, so you can hide the cast.

```
public static class A
{
    // please note: some example in related to your question
    // and the strategy pattern provided at the link
    public static P GetI(int a)
    {
        if (a == 1)
            return new I();
        else
            return null; // <- this is important for evaluation
    }

    // can put this method anywhere else, also into another class
    public static P GetO(int a)
    {
        if (a == 2)
            return new O();
        else
            return null; // <- this is important for evaluation
    }

    public static bool Condition(string pci)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(pci); // could eval different states, values
    }
}
```

Then it is possible to divide the as/is logic into separate methods/classes and the calling class (e.g. controller, client) doesn't need to know all the different specializations.
The following code shows how to create the context. See my [posting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819747/how-to-decouple-mode-switching-and-commands) for the implementation details of Strategy and Context class.

```
var strategyI = new Strategy<int, P>(A.Condition, A.GetI);
var strategyO = new Strategy<int, P>(A.Condition, A.GetO);

var strategies = new List<Strategy<int, P>> {strategyI, strategyO};
var context = new Context<int, P>(strategies.ToArray());

var result = context.Evaluate(1); // should return a new I(), with 2 as param a new O()

// once you get the result you can create a new context to work with the result

var strategyWorkI = new Strategy<P, P>(Condition, WorkWithI);
var stragegiesForWork = new List<Strategy<P, P>> {strategyWorkI} // could be more than one
var workContext = new Context<P, P>(strategiesForWork.ToArray());

var p = workContext.Evaluate(result); // does the right thing, but
                                      // no need to know class I here (only P)
if (p == null)
  // seems to be something went wrong, throw? ...
```

And here is the decoupling for the cast but you still need a cast at this point.

```
public static P WorkWithI(P p)
{
    var i = p as I; // I would prefer as instead of is (see boxing/unboxing in .net)
    if (i != null)
    {
       // do what you want with concrete class I in i
    }

    return i; // <- this is important for Evaluation
}
```

Anyway... there is still Point in the code with an is/as, but it does not influence your controller / manager etc. (keeps code flexible and pluggable, e.g. via Dependency Injection)

... I can provide a full example if you can't understand my short description.

Comment: Dude, you are right. Downvoting without leaving a comment is bad, no question. But i think maybe you try to hard. Kassem and Honoured Chow pointed in the right direction. IMO without knowing further context the abstract method is the preferred solution because whatsoever @Chase Fields explicitly wanted to eliminate the cast what your solutions do not provide.

Answer (score -1):

If all above solutions not fitting your requirements and you don't want to change the base class (adding properties from derrived classes) then you should also think not only about your inheritance design as mentioned by most comments... **you should also look for your factory/repository implementation**. Is this repository doing the thing you need? Why not add a GetI() and GetO()?

For eample Linq allows you to query and filter a List with using .OfType and you get only elements of Type T.

You can add a specific Get Method with type info (e.g. with [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as I did in my example) and an additional condition.

```
public T Get<T>(string pci, int c)
{
     var a = GetAByPCI(string pci);

     if(a == c)
         return new T();
     else
         // throw exception here.
}
```

Call the method Get with the generic param. The problem of this solution here is that you need to know the condition at the call time and this does not handle "special constructions" (e.g. constructor with params for T). Anyway this could be solved with the factory pattern, too.

```
I i = PRepository<I>.Get(1, "200"); // create a new I(), only if 1 fits GetAByPCI()
O o = PRepository<O>.Get(2, "123"); // create a new O(), only if 2 fits GetAByPCI()
// can do anything with the concrete type
```

You could also move the condition out of the repository/factory call with the strategy pattern (already mentioned in my answer above).

It is also possible to wrap up the "as" behind the generic method (I show you how even if I would not recommend it in most cases).

```
public T Get<T>(string pci)
{
     return this.Get(pci) as T; // your method with trying to cast to concrete type
}
```

This way you can get the implementation as follows:

```
I i = PRepository<I>.Get("200");
if (i != null)
{
  // do I specific tasks
}
```